# Postgres create timestamp ( current date + specific time ) format

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd love to have timestamp which composed of
`<[current date] + [specific time I can specify as a string]>`.

Ex.
2016-03-08 23:59:59

- 2016-03-08 => current date
- 23:59:59 => I can specify

I'd love to do something like

`cast(cast( now()::timestamp(0) AS string) || '23:59:59' ) AS timestamp )`

in more postgres way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
CURRENT_DATE + TIME '23:59:59'
```

I don't have access to a database atm so I can't test it out for you but I find Table 9-27 in the link below to be very useful (I find that whole webpage to be very useful).

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: Almost right. `CURRENT_DATE + TIME '23:59:59'` (without `date`).

Comment: Just tested it out on my local server. You are absolutely right Egor. Edited my answer to take into account your correction.